# Getters disappear when object is returned in another object?

Tags: javascript, object

I am coding the game Battleship and have the following code for a `Ship` factory function:

```js
const Ship = (len) => {
  const length = len;
  let _hitNumber = 0;
  const hit = () => {
    _hitNumber = _hitNumber + 1;
    return _hitNumber
  };
  return {
    length,
    get hitNumber() {
      return _hitNumber;
    },
    hit,
  };
};

const ship = Ship(3);
ship.hit();
console.log(ship.hitNumber);
```

It works as expected. If I call `hit()`  and then examine `.hitNumber` it has increased. I then made a `Fleet` factory as shown below. It returns an array of Ships:

```js
const Ship = (len) => {
  const length = len;
  let _hitNumber = 0;
  const hit = () => {
    _hitNumber = _hitNumber + 1;
    return _hitNumber
  };
  return {
    length,
    get hitNumber() {
      return _hitNumber;
    },
    hit,
  };
};

const Fleet = () => {
  return [{
      name: "Carrier",
      ...Ship(5),
    },
    {
      name: "Battleship",
      ...Ship(4),
    },
  ]
}

const testFleet = Fleet();
testFleet[0].hit();
console.log(testFleet[0].hitNumber)
```

But now calling `hit` doesn't work:

It's as if `.hitNumber` is not a getter anymore or `testFleet[0].hit()` doesn't refer to `testFleet[0]`'s `_hitnumber`.

I'd like help understanding what is going on and whether it is the array brackets or the spread operator that is responsible. I suspect that the pitfalls outlined in [this article](https://dev.to/parenttobias/getters-and-setters-in-javascript-whats-the-point-43bo) are relevant, but my situation is different enough (and my understanding is shallow enough) that I can't quite make the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Ship()` function, you return an object with a getter, then you later use the spread operator to copy all properties of the ship to a new object.

Behind the scenes, the getters are syntactic sugar for calls to [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). `Object.defineProperty()` can set special settings on properties, such as calling a function when a property is access (this is a getter).

However, the spread operator simply copies properties from one object to another, and does not copy the special settings set by `Object.defineProperty()`. So, when the spread operator tries to copy the `hitNumber` property, it calls the getter once and copies the result, not the function itself.

To fix this you need to implement your own replacement for the spread operator that can copy accessors (getters and setters). Luckily, the issue is common enough that MDN provides a function [in the documentation for `Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#copying_accessors). Here is an example with your code:

```js
// from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#copying_accessors
function completeAssign(target, ...sources) {
  sources.forEach((source) => {
    const descriptors = Object.keys(source).reduce((descriptors, key) => {
      descriptors[key] = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key);
      return descriptors;
    }, {});

    Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source).forEach((sym) => {
      const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, sym);
      if (descriptor.enumerable) {
        descriptors[sym] = descriptor;
      }
    });
    Object.defineProperties(target, descriptors);
  });
  return target;
}


const Ship = (len) => {
  const length = len;
  let _hitNumber = 0;
  const hit = () => {
    _hitNumber = _hitNumber + 1;
    return _hitNumber
  };

  return {
    length,
    get hitNumber() {
      return _hitNumber;
    },
    hit,
  };
};

const Fleet = () => {
  const arr = [{
      name: "Carrier",
      len: 5,
    },
    {
      name: "Battleship",
      len: 5,
    },
  ];

  arr.forEach(obj => {
    completeAssign(obj, Ship(obj.len));
  });
  return arr;
}

const fleet = Fleet();
fleet[0].hit();
console.log(fleet[0].hitNumber);
```

Comment: Thank you! It bothers me that if I console.log(fleet[0]) hitNumber is still shown as a getter. I suppose it still is a getter, but one that is referencing what's at Ship(4)'s _hitNumber, not at fleet[0]'s _hitNumber.